# Reference an image based on props in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a component that renders an image. The image will be different based on an api call and the data being returned.

Based on api call I will get a string such as the following:

{
assetName: 'company123'
}

I would like to pass this prop down to the component which will then reference an image we have for that name.

/images/company123.png

```
<img src={'/images/${assetName}.png'} />
```

Typically I would just import the image and use it but this is not possible when I need to change the image based on the prop value.

How can I achieve the above?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mixing the quotations with backticks string concatenation and it should be the backticks instead.

```
<img src={`/images/${assetName}.png`} />
```

**Note:** This is called template literals. (Thanks, Chris).

[More on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Nice. You should add that this is called *template literals*.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I understand the syntax was incorrect but it would still not solve the problem.

Comment: Mmh, can you check the path on developer tools of your browser?